# jqModal popup not working

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I have been trying to get a basic jqModal popup and I am getting stuck. The jqModal.css file is properly hiding the popup box (before it's activated), but I can't get it to popup.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Modal test </title>
<link href="jqModal.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jqModal.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#modal-pop").jqm();
    $("h1").html("how are you?");
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color:red;}
#modal-pop {background-color:green;
            width:50px;
            height:60px;}
</style>    
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<a href="#" class="jqModal">view</a> 
<div id="modal-pop" class="jqmWindow">This is a neat popup!</div>
</body>
```

When I comment out the line

```
$("#modal-pop").jqm();
```

then the next line

```
$("h1").html("how are you?");
```

works, otherwise it doesn't. I checked the path, jqModal.js is really located in the root directory as is in the code.

Comment: You should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on another post I saw, I figured out the issue. The script tag with the source of jquery.js needs to be before the script for jqModal.js, since it is a plugin of jquery and needs the jquery code to run.